# Impossible to umount /mnt

Tags: debian, mount, zfs, unmounting

I am running Debian kFreeBSD wheezy. Accidentally I mounted my zfs pool directly into /mnt. When I try to unmount I get an error:

```
zfs unmount myzfspool
cannot unmount '/mnt': Device or resource busy
```

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filesystem mounted on /mnt has open file descriptors from running processes. You normally could try an umount with the force option, but looking up those processes with **"lsof /mnt"** and end them is safer.